# which one is right? which one is not passive? what is these difference?

Tags: passive-voice

Which one is right? and what is their differences?
And, what is your reason?

> How has the meaning changed?
>
> How has the meaning been changed?

Answer (score 1):

`How has the meaning changed?` is active, whereas

`How has the meaning been changed?` is passive.

In the active example, the meaning is the noun that performs the verb, and thus, it is active.

IN the passive example, the word "been" implies that the verb is performed by another subject. -- Which is what makes it passive.